# Assigning values to matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a 31x51 matrix using:

```
ij_array = np.zeros((31,51))
```

I would like to assign values to each of the matrix positions based on the value of the column. For example, I would like it to be 2*(column value) which goes from 0 to 50. So the first column would be full of 0s, second would be 2s, third would be 4s, etc.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

Comment: Something like `arr = np.meshgrid(range(31), np.ones(51)); print(arr[0]*arr[1])` as a starting point, you'll need to work out how to get the increments in 2's

Comment: The shape of this array is 31x51, not 30x50

Answer (score 0):

```
ij_array = np.repeat(2*np.arange(51)[np.newaxis,:],31,axis=0)
```